# Почему происходит и есть ли правило редукции согласных звуков рядом с сонорными "Н" и "Л"?

Tags: орфоэпия, фонетика, согласные

Например:
слово спрашивают про слово охотник, в котором "Т" произносится не так как обычно, а без голоса; есть разница в произношении слов "отмыть" и "отлить" - в первом примере "Т" слышится отчетливо как отдельный звук, а во втором произносится глухо и без звука.

Дело скорее всего касается глухих звуков, потому что звонкие можно произносить как обычно (хотя, их тоже можно несколько редуцировать, приглушать и смягчать).

Думаю, должно быть какое-то правило для сонорных "Л" и "Н" в отличие от "М" и "Н" с которыми согласные произносятся более обычно.

Нашёл [на форуме](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=34604.0) ссылку на статью, видимо похожий эффект в разных языках мира:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release

Также там есть сложные слова которые я вряд ли пойму, но может вам это о чём-то говорит: бм, пм, дн, тн, в том числе мягкие - фаукальные;
дл, тл, в том числе мягкие - латеральные аффрикаты.

Comment: Вы пишете: «..."Т" произносится не так как обычно, а без голоса». Разве "Т" может когда-либо произноситься с голосом? Ведь это глухой звук, в отличие от его пары – звонкого "Д".  А что значит: «"Л" и "Н" в отличие от "М" и "Н"»?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да, с любым звонким звуком, либо сонорным Р, М: отмашь, тварь - Т слышится отчетливо. С "Н" сложнее, в общем нашёл статью вики по ссылке на форуме, добавил в вопрос. Ну и еще какие-то термины, не знаю насколько это поясняет суть проблемы).

Comment: Ничё не понимаю, честно. :)  Куда Вы залезли, да ещё "по-нерусски"?.. Интересно, с какой целью интересуетесь? По-моему, всё просто: ТЛЯ, ТМЯ, ТРЯ, ТНЯ – первый звук глухой, ДЛЯ, ДМЯ, ДРЯ, ДНЯ – звонкий.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец он не просто глухой, он без звучный, то есть: удар языка и воздух, без голоса. Залез, потому что вопрос задал человек, который русский язык учит, иностранец, оказалось что проблема не такая простая, как кажется, и это не просто оглушение, а другое, по крайней мере я так слышу. А в стандартных правилах есть только оглушение, а эффект сочетания тн, тл и тд как отдельный не рассматривается, хотя звуки Т разные. Сочетание ТВ например, можно со звуком Т произнести, можно уменьшить звук, но ТЛ со звуком не катит совсем, как ни старайся - получается вообще кривое звучание.

Comment: Конечно, последующий звук влияет на артикуляцию и восприятие Т, но это, кажется, запредельные тонкости (как говорится, наш Т и в Африке Т). Ладно... Может, кто-нибудь шарит в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу свою версию.

**Специальных** правил редукции  согласных звуков рядом с сонорными Н и Л для  носителей языка, как я думаю, нет. Сонорные согласные даже используются для **проверки** глухих/звонких согласных в слабой позиции, как и гласные: *дорожка — дорожный, березка — березняк*.

**Для иностранцев** — другое дело. Почему ***охотник*** можно произнести как ***охо(д)ник***? Дело в том что в русском языке выделяется группа **зубных согласных** с одинаковым местом образования: ***Т, Д, З, С, Ц, Л, Н,*** и оба согласных входят в эту группу.

```
  Зубные согласные названы в соответствии с местом своего 
  образования (при произношении зубных согласных кончик 
  языка упирается в основании передних зубов), а различаются 
  они по способу образования и по наличию или отсутствию 
  голоса (для звонких и глухих зубных согласных).
  Звуки Т и Д относятся к группе смычных согласных (струя 
  воздуха разрывает препятствие, или смычку, языка и зубов 
  при их произношении).  Звуки Л и Н – сонорные звуки (Н – 
  носовой звук, а Л – боковой), струя воздуха при их 
  произношении проходит через носовую полость или с боковых 
  частей языка соответственно. Отметим также, что М — не 
  зубный звук, а губно-губный.
```

Звуки ***Д*** и ***Н*** имеют **одинаковое** место образования, а это повод для того, чтобы произнести их одинаково, то есть **звонко**. Но по способу образования звуки **различны**. Носители языка без особого труда произносят глухой ***Т*** и звонкий ***Н***,  а иностранцам сделать это сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, глухие согласные звуки, такие как "Т", могут быть произнесены без голоса в некоторых случаях, например, если они находятся в конце слова или перед другим глухим согласным звуком. Однако, произношение может различаться в зависимости от диалекта и индивидуальных особенностей речи.

Сонорные звуки, такие как "Л" и "Н", как правило, произносятся более отчетливо и сильнее выражены, чем глухие согласные звуки. Однако, произношение этих звуков может также зависеть от контекста и наличия других звуков в слове.

Comment: Вы пишете: «...глухие согласные звуки, такие как "Т", могут быть произнесены без голоса в некоторых случаях...» Звук "Т" вроде бы всегда (а не в некоторых случаях) произносится без голоса.

Answer (score 0):

Различие в восприятии звука "Т" может быть связано с изменением тона голоса. Изменение голоса волнообразно с пиком на ударных гласных. В слове "отмыть" Т на восходящей ветви волны, в слове "охотник" - на нисходящей. То есть звук может быть одинаковым, а его восприятие разным. Без точных измерений невозможно установить, истинность или ложность утверждения: В слове охотник "Т" произносится не так как обычно, а без голоса.